# Tentando realizar um acesso de um valor dentro de um dicionário em Python, porém acabo recebendo um erro ao printar rodar o código

Tags: python, dicionário

Estava criando um dicionario brincando com pokemon em python no pycharm Comunity, mas quando fui realizar o acesso do dicionário, me foi devolvido uma mensagem de erro no código ao tentar printar um dos valores dentro de uma chave no dicionário que por sua vez também há outros dicionários dentro:

```py
print(f'O pokemon {pesquisa} é de estagio {pk["stage"]}')
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

No caso para fazer o código começar a rodar é preciso escrever Charmander
Sou iniciante no python e gostaria de saber como resolver isso, segue o código abaixo:

```
pokemons = {
    'Charmander': {
        'stage': '1',
        'tipo': 'fogo',
        'evoluções': {
            'charmilion': {
                'stage': '2',
                'tipo': 'fogo',
                'evoluções': {
                    'charizard': {
                        'stage': '3',
                        'tipo': 'fogo/voador',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

pesquisa = str(input('Qual pokemon gostaria de saber mais sobre? '))
if pesquisa in pokemons:
    for pk, pv in pokemons[pesquisa].items():
        print(f'O pokemon {pesquisa} é de estagio {pk["stage"]}')
else:
    print('Este pokemon não existe')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece porque no seu loop, `pk` é o nome da chave, sendo assim uma `string`. A `string` só pode ter índice inteiro.

```
>>> a = "Teste"
>>> a["stage"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

>>> a[1]
'e'
```

Sendo asism, basta alterar esta parte

```
if pesquisa in pokemons:
    for pk, pv in pokemons[pesquisa].items():
        print(f'O pokemon {pesquisa} é de estagio {pk["stage"]}')
```

para

```
if pesquisa in pokemons:
   print(f'O pokemon {pesquisa} é de estagio {pokemons[pesquisa].get("stage", "não tenho esta informação")}')
```

A utilização do `get` é para dar a oportunidade de no caso da chave `stage` não existir o código não gerar uma exceção.

Existem outras formas, mas esta estaria dentro de sua lógica.

**Update**

Para pegar as evoluções seria algo como abaixo:

```
if pesquisa in pokemons:
   print(f"{pesquisa} é um pokemon no estágio {pokemons[pesquisa]['stage']}")
   for pokemon2, dados_pokemon2 in pokemons[pesquisa]['evoluções'].items():
       print(f"{pokemon2} é evolução de {pesquisa} e é estágio {dados_pokemon2['stage']}")
       for pokemon3, dados_pokemon3 in dados_pokemon2['evoluções'].items():
           print(f"{pokemon3} é evolução de {pokemon2} e é estágio {dados_pokemon3['stage']}")
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Entendi muito obrigado, ajudou bastante, mas e no caso de  eu querer imprimir após isso as evoluções? Tipo após imprimir isso também imprimir da mesma forma as informações das evoluções, por exemplo 'O pokemon 
Charmande é de estágio 1' da logo abaixo 'sendo  suas evoluções: Charmilion de estagio 2'. Como eu faria para acessar esse segundo dicionário e imprimir suas chaves?

Comment: @Kaique, veja o update.

Comment: muito obrigado, me ajudou a compreender bem mais agora, muito agradecido.

Comment: @Kaique, que bom que ajudou. Caso ache pertinente, marque a resposta como solução e vote positivo. :)